# Mysql: update command not changing

Tags: mysql, sql

2017-05-30 --> 20170530

```
 SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

 UPDATE stations.attenuation_smoothed
 SET date = DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y/%m/%d') 
 WHERE counter = 1;

 SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

I have also tried update.....replicate

But the table shows no effect, the query runs without error saying

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: post table schema... `date` is reserved word, should be in ``, and if the field is `date` type, that operation will do nothing

Comment: What's date column's data type?

Comment: @FlashThunder it is an exception to that rule. Otherwise the OP would have got an error.

Comment: @FlashThunder no, this is not version dependent, see http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: The important part of Flash's comment is:  If `date` is a `date` data type, the assignment is tautological -- it does nothing.  MySQL does not update a row if nothing changes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just a little question about your last sentence. Is it only MySQL that does that? Or did you say MySQL only because the question is about it? In other words, if the database was SQL-Server or Oracle, would the result be any different?

Comment: @RacilHilan . . . It depends on the database.  SQL Server updates rows even when there are no changes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, that's what I thought. I didn't know MySQL wouldn't update if no changes, probably because I never though it should happen. Frankly, I find that rather silly. Issuing an update statement with no changes is likely to be a mistake or bad logic, so why punish all good queries with superfluous checks? Anyway, thank you for the info and kind reply.

Comment: date data type is date

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't "count" rows that aren't modified as being "affected". That is, if we assign values to columns that result in "no change" to the row, the row isn't included in the "row(s) affected" count.

---

The question doesn't specify the *datatype* of the column named `date`.

If that's `DATE` datatype, then we would expect the `UPDATE` statement (as shown in the question) to not modify any rows, and to return "0 row(s) affected".

If it's character datatype, and if the value that is already stored in the column is in format `'YYYY/MM/DD'` represents a valid date value, then we also expect the return to be "0 row(s) affected".

---

To demonstrate why the statement is not making any change to the row, consider this demonstration:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-12','%Y/%m/%d')                  AS str
     , DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-12','%Y/%m/%d') + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS dt
```

returns:

```
str         dt
----------  ----------
2018/04/12  2018-04-12
```

The `DATE` datatype is an internal representation. MySQL uses a standard format **`YYYY-MM-DD`** when converting from the internal representation into character string.

The demonstration query is using explicit call to `DATE_FORMAT` to convert a `DATE` (or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`) value into a string representation, in a specified format.

Note that the dash separators that appear in the string representation aren't actually part of the `DATE` value, those are characters that appear in the string representation.

When we assign a string to a DATE column, there's an implicit conversion of that string into `DATE` datatype.  And MySQL is fairly lenient about the delimiters and the format.  Consider

```
SELECT DATE( '2018/4/12' ) AS dt1
     , DATE( '2018.4+12' ) AS dt2
```

This demonstrates converting a string value into `DATE` datatype.

```
dt1         dt2
----------  ----------
2018-04-12  2018-04-12
```

To return the `DATE` value in a resultset, MySQL is converting the `DATE` value back into a string representation it's converted back to a string representation  (in MySQL default format.)

---

And to demonstrate why there is "no change" in the case that `date` is a character column, consider:

```
SELECT DATE('2018/04/12')                             AS dt
     , DATE_FORMAT( DATE('2018/04/12') ,'%Y/%m/%d')   AS str
```

returns

```
dt          str
----------  ----------
2018-04-12  2018/04/12
```

---

I'm not sure any of that answers the question that was asked. I'm not even sure there was a question asked.